Встал вопрос, как принудительно вызвать Bitrix24 обработчик afterDealAddHandler для конвертации лида в дилс
Встал вопрос, как принудительно (в ручную) вызвать Bitrix24 обработчик (Handler afterDealAddHandler) для конвертации лида в дилс (Lead to Deals).
Удалось собрать вот такой вызов
$event = new Bitrix\Main\Event("crm", "OnAfterCrmDealAdd", ['arFields' => $fieldsBX]);
$event->send();

При этом внутри самого обработчика приходит не привычный массив, а объект Event.
Как направить стандартный объект, может кто знает?
Пока пришлось вставить первой строкой фильтр внутри самого обработчика
 public static function afterDealAddHandler($arFields)
    {
        if (!is_array($arFields)) $arFields = $arFields->getParameter('arFields');//for $event income
     ...
     }


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.
